# string to ByteArray convertion using objective c

Tags: objective-c

please help with me i am in new in objective c or c programming, i am struggle in this calculation based on data conversion

byte b1 =

```
 hexStringToByteArray(workingData.charAt(begin));

      String bbb= String.valueOf(b1);
        int ch1 = ((b1 & 0xC0) >> 6);
        String ccc=  String.valueOf(ch1);
        int ch2 = ((b1 & 0x30) >> 4);
        String dddd=  String.valueOf(ch2);
        dtc += dtcLetters[ch1];
        String eeee=  String.valueOf(dtcLetters[ch1]);
        dtc += hexArray[ch2];
        String eeeedd=  String.valueOf( hexArray[ch2]);
        dtc += workingData.substring(begin + 1, 
begin + 4);

        String dfdf=  String.valueOf(workingData.substring(begin + 1, begin + 4));
        if (dtc.equals("P0000")) {
            return;
        }
        codes.append(dtc);
        codes.append('\n');
    }
}

private byte hexStringToByteArray(char s) {
    return (byte) ((Character.digit(s, 16) << 
4));
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit the question.

Comment: That's Objective-C?